# How to Put Image into PDF

Tags: visualforce-template

I am creating the PDF by using Templates, i want to paste the image In PDF file i am using another server URL, it's working fine for me For Visualforce templates, it's not working for the PDF which was creating by using templates

my code is--

```
<messaging:attachment renderAs="pdf" filename="{!relatedTo.name}">

<apex:imageurl="http://skin.xxxxxxx.com/skin/frontend/enterprise/xxxxx_2013/images/xxxx-header_logo.png"/><br/>

Hello {!recipient.name},<br/>
```

when i use above Server URL it is working fine for me for visualforce templates,
  when i used for PDF creation it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of things you can try:

1. add `http://skin.xxxxxxx.com/` as a Remote Site Setting,
2. use the `<img />` tag instead of the `<apex:image />` tag,
3. localize the file into your org using a Static Resource

Comment: I do all things what you mention but it not showing in PDF file  <img url="http://skin.xxxxx.com/skin/frontend/enterprise/xxxx_2013/images/xxxx-header_logo.png"/><br/>

Comment: You need to keep the "http://" prefix. I tried user320's suggestions 1 and 3 and both worked. 1 seems the simplest way to go.

Comment: @keith Prefix means my Salesforce Instance.? could  you paste your code once .

Comment: @Sathya No I mean the full URL that allows you to view the image in your browser. In fact my comment was wrong: I think you did have the full URL and it is the automatic conversion to links by the site's markdown processing that made me think you had dropped it.

Comment: Can you use <img/> in a renderAsPDF? Sure there were issues with that once upon a time?

Comment: @user293 works for me Phil

Comment: Hmm, perhaps a legacy thing - sure there was something, thanks for clarifying